# Manifest v3 background scripts/service worker on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, service-worker, browser-extension

I'm trying to migrate my browser extension (that I expect to work on Chrome and Firefox) from manifest v2 to v3.

However, I am getting conflicting information about the `background` section. I did lots of research on google and stack overflow, and no one seems to agree on anything. Also, most information seems to be outdated. Of the best sources I found, lots of places mention that it should be migrated to `service_worker` ([example](https://www.vshsolutions.com/blogs/chrome-extension-manifest-v3-a-migration-guide/)), but it seems that Firefox should still use `scripts` instead ([source](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/manifest-v3-migration-guide/)).

But no matter what I do, I am getting errors. If I only use service worker:

```
"background": {
    "type": "module", // tried both with and without this option
    "service_worker": "background.ts"
}
```

The the build command from `parcel` is happy (seems to use `parcel/transformer-webextension` underneath), but `web-ext` fails catastrophically:

```
WebExtError: installTemporaryAddon: Error:
Error: Could not install add-on at '...':
Error: background.service_worker is currently disabled
```

Even if I provide the flag `--firefox-preview` which was supposed to fix this.

Which kinda makes sense, [this well-written tutorial](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/manifest-v3-migration-guide/) claims that Firefox is keeping using `scripts` for V3, just deprecating the `persisent` flag (which you can remove or set to false). That is fine, as I wasn't using that anyway.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.ts"],
    "persistent": false // `persistent` must either be false or omited; I tried both
}
```

In fact that is exactly how [the official Firefox docs claim V3 should support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts#specify_the_background_scripts).

But parcel complains that `^^^ Missing property service\_worker`:

[image: screenshot of parcel error]

Ok, so let's try both:

```
"background": {
    "type": "module",
    "service_worker": "background.ts",
    "scripts": ["background.ts"]
},
```

But parcel is not happy, with `Invalid Web Extension manifest`:

[image: screenshot of parcel error]

So no matter what I try, I can't get both `parcel` and `web-ext` to be happy at the same time.

It seems that Chrome wants one thing, and Firefox wants another, but no matter what I try, I can't even run my extension on *neither* browser. So not only it seems I can't have a V3 extension for both browsers - I cannot have a V3 extension at all if I want to use both `parcel` and `web-ext` (which is indispensable afaik).

I am particularly concerned because according [to official chrome sources](https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/manifest-v-3-migration-timeline-update), Manifest V3 is a "prerequisite for the Featured badge⁠" starting of *now*, and V2 will be removed by June.

So if I am already penalized for not using V3 now, and have less than 6 months to figure out how to, while none of the available tooling seems to support this version yet? I must be missing something...

---

Notes: these are the commands I am using to run parcel and web-ext:

```
        "watch": "parcel watch src/manifest.json --dist-dir distribution --no-cache --no-hmr",
        "start": "web-ext run --firefox-preview"
```

And these are the versions I am using, both the latest on NPM

```
        "parcel": "^2.8.2",
        "web-ext": "^7.4.0",
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just faced the same problem:

- Chrome is not happy with `background.scripts` and insists on using `background.service_worker`
- Firefox doesn't support `background.service_worker` and wants `background.scripts`

Manifest v3 is developed by Google, so looks like Firefox team haven't fully implemented it yet. Firefox 109 is the first version to "support" manifest v3 (released on January 17).

I was able to quickly find these tickets [1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1578286) and [2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1573659) on bugzilla. Doesn't look like it will be fixed any time soon!

What makes matters even worse, Chrome doesn't accept new extensions to its store with manifest v2 any more! This could be the reason why Firefox team decided to enable Manifest v3 extensions even without service workers support.

`web-ext` is also developed by Mozilla, just having something like this:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

should allow you (no cross-browser compatibility!) to publish it to Firefox marketplace and use `web-ext` tool (it also has very verbose inbuilt lint subcommand `./node_modules/.bin/web-ext lint`)

Comment: So I ended up having two manifests, one for each browser, however I still can't use `import` in my background.js file in Firefox (it works fine in chrome with `type: "module"` added to service_worker block.

Comment: FWIW, added a simple npm package for converting between the v3 flavors: https://github.com/brettz9/convert-manifest-format

Comment: This answer is great to know why Firefox supports MV3 but not service workers. https://vite-plugin-web-extension.aklinker1.io/guide/supporting-multiple-browsers.html supports defining a single `manifest.json` that supports both MV2 & MV3 based on browser or alternatively, separate files. It uses web-ext and vite. Any property can be prefixed with`{{platform}}`, e.g. `"{{chrome}}.service_worker": "src/background.ts",` and `"{{firefox}}.scripts": ["src/background.ts"]`.

Comment: For simple extensions and no bundler, templating of manifest.json might be enough. There is example here: https://github.com/jsnjack/surfly-protocol/commit/82df54772c4361c9569489b78d9bc1a55bca6758 . Makefile is used to build both Chrome and Firefox versions

Comment: it doesn't look like V3 is supported by Firefox at all. Content scripts are not injected. Using V2 it is.

Comment: @JobaDiniz actually.. at least during temporarily loading an addon using `about:debugging` I can confirm, that the `content.js` is loading and working (Manifest V3). `background.service_worker` is not loaded though.

Answer (score 11):

I looked through the parcel-bundler change history and Manifest V3 support [was added](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7050) in April, 2022 before [Mozilla provided details](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2022/05/18/manifest-v3-in-firefox-recap-next-steps/) of their Manifest V3 implementation, which does not include Chrome's addition of Service Workers to replace Background Pages.

Still today, Mozilla has only provided [high level details](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2022/11/17/manifest-v3-signing-available-november-21-on-firefox-nightly/) on their vision for Manifest v3, which leaves Firefox's implementation half complete, and (notable to this post) distinct from Chrome's implementation when a background script is included.

This presents several issues for Parcel because their bundler relies on a consistent manifest standard to produce a single distributable that can be used across browsers. The issue you raised is valid and Parcel only supports Chrome's version of Manifest v3. The bigger problem is that Firefox will require a distinct manifest file from other browsers for the foreseeable future, and parcel-bundler only supports a single manifest file that [must be named 'manifest.json'](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/blob/c3bbe0a6160186f496ca2f9e9bead9376c0522f1/packages/runtimes/webextension/src/WebExtensionRuntime.js#L18).

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/website/pull/1052) to add support for multiple manifest files using distinct names, but it has not been merged yet (at the time of writing). I'm not sure how suitable this solution will be since the changes do not solve for this specific issue.

I [opened a bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/8785) in the parcel-bundler repo to document the incompatibility with Firefox Manifest V3, but at the moment it is not possible to build a Manifest V3 extension for Firefox that includes background scripts using Parcel.

Comment: your guthub issue was closed saying it has been completed in a PR... but the problem still occurs even using a version released after the PR merge :(

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Firefox continues to use `scripts` and Google Chrome continues to use `service_worker`.
In the latest Firefox/Google Chrome, no error will occur even if both are listed.

So let's try:

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.ts",
    "scripts": ["background.ts"]
},
```

> - Before Chrome 121, Chrome refuses to load a Manifest V3 extension with `background.scripts` or `background.page` present. **From Chrome 121, their presence in a Manifest V3 extension is ignored.**
> - Before Firefox 120, Firefox did not start the background page if `service_worker` was present (see Firefox bug 1860304). **From Firefox 121, the background page starts as expected, regardless of the presence of `service_worker`.**
>
> [background - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background#browser_support)

Refs:
[Proposal: declaring background scripts in a neutral way · Issue #282 · w3c/webextensions](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/282)